# Run supertest e2e with dynamic url for different environments using cli

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, e2e-testing, ts-jest, supertest

I have a nestjs backend api server within a monorepo. I want to do integration test using supertest. I have currently configured e2e against `jest --env=node --verbose` command in package.json.
For example, check if http://localhost:8112/health return OK.

```
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const res = await request(http://localhost:8112/health)
    .get('/health')
    .expect(200);
     expect(res.text).toEqual('OK');
 });
```

I want the api url  endpoint to be dynamic. If its staging stg-xyz.com/health or if prod prod-xyz.com.
How do i achieve the same?

Comment: Option 1. environment variables Option 2. Get the API endpoint from some kind of configuration center service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two separate ts files where two different environment variables are specified like below:

```
process.env = Object.assign(process.env, {
  SERVICE_API_TEST_URL: 'http://localhost:8112',
  DEFAULT_TIMEOUT: 60000,
});
```

we can switch the file passing as cli agrument setupfile

```
nx run api-server:e2e --setupFile=apps/api-server/e2e-test-stg-environment.ts

nx run api-server:e2e --setupFile=apps/api-server/e2e-test-dev-environment.ts
```